# react-fabricjs package doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, redux, fabricjs

I'm going to use the Fabric.js for React project.
I found the react-fabricjs package and imported it to the project.

But it doesn't work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { fabric, Canvas, Circle, Image, Path, Text } from 'react-fabricjs';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { ActionCreators } from '../../redux/action'
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import Notifications, {notify} from 'react-notify-toast';
import * as controller from '../../lib/controller'

import FileDrop from '../../component/FileDrop'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import FeedbackList from '../../component/FeedbackList'
import FirebaseMedia from '../../component/FeedbackList/media'
import DeleteForm from '../../component/Delete'


require('./index.css')
const sample_word = require('../../resource/images/sample-word.png')
const sample_video = require('../../resource/images/sample-video.png')
const sample_audio = require('../../resource/images/sample-audio.png')
const sample_pdf = require('../../resource/images/sample-pdf.png')
const loadingIcon = require('../../resource/gif/loading.svg')
...
<div className="full-item">
     <div className="full-item-inner">
          <canvas id="c"
                  ref="canvas"
                  width="1000"
                  height="1000">
                  <Image ref="image"
                        imgElement={document.getElementById('my-image')}
                        width={100}
                        height={100}/>
          </canvas>
          <img id="my-image" alt="" src={this.state.workContent} />
     </div>
</div>
```

I am not familiar with React/Redux.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found why the react-fabricjs package didn't work on my end.
Because the react-fabricjs doesn't support the Typescript so I can't import the module from that package.

So I decided to use **@types/fabric** for my project.

```
npm install --save @types/fabric
```

I hope it helps for the other devs.

Comment: HI, Will it be woking if we simply install this. For me its not working

Comment: Well would you provide about issue in more detail? @Dinesh

Comment: @jini   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bool' of undefined , thi eror i am getting in the console